# How to pass userdefined table type to MSSQL request from Java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Given a simple stored procedure which has a table with a single column of integers as argument:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[table_sel]
@tbl INT32Table READONLY
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT value FROM @tbl
END
```

How do I execute this stored procedure from Java? From C# this does what I want:

```
SqlConnection sqlconn;
System.Data.DataTable tbl = new System.Data.DataTable("INT32Table", "dbo");
tbl.Columns.Add("value", typeof(int));
tbl.Rows.Add(2);
tbl.Rows.Add(3);
tbl.Rows.Add(5);
tbl.Rows.Add(7);
tbl.Rows.Add(11);
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("table_sel"))
{
    command.Connection = sqlconn;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tbl", tbl);
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Cannt pass TVP's using JDBC. The Microsoft JDBC team is still working on this as they mentioned 2 years ago. Refer the Link :

### visit : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jdbcteam/archive/2012/04/03/how-would-you-use-table-valued-parameters-tvp.aspx

Try some alternate solution instead of using TVP's by passing XML parameter and with OPENXML() in procedure body.

Answer (score 1):

Oh sorry,
as far as I know there's no such table object in Java, you can use cs.setObject() but then again you should obtain that object from somewhere (query on mssql server ?).
If you're looking for performance on inserts with JDBC then you should consider preparedStatements and batch execution.

```
java.sql.connection connection = //driver, url, database, credentials ...

try
{
    PreparedStatement ps =
        connection.prepareStatement("insert into tbl values (?)");
    ps.setInt(1, your 1st int);
    ps.addBatch();
    ps.setInt(1, your 2nd int);
    ps.addBatch();
    ps.setInt(1, your 3rd int);
    ps.addBatch();
    ps.executeBatch();
}
catch (SQLException e)
{
    // err handling goes here
}
finally
{
    // close your resources
}
```

Regards
S

Comment: I'm looking for batch queries. That is I wish to make one large query and get a lot of results.

Comment: +1. This might help me do what I want, but as it does not answer the question, I will not accept it.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you should use CallableStatement.
eg.

```
java.sql.connection connection = //driver, url, database, credentials ...

try
{
    CallableStatement cs =
        connection.prepareCall("{ call table_sel(?) }");
    cs.setInt(1, your int);
    cs.execute();
}
catch (SQLException e)
{
    // err handling goes here
}
finally
{
    // close your ressources
}
```

Regards
S

Comment: My problem is not calling a stored procedure, it is calling a stored procedure with a table as the argument. The point of the exercise is to pass an array of integers to the stored procedure. In your example you are passing just one. Basically: What do I write instead of "ca.setInt(1, int)" in order to pass a table?