# How pass structure datatype to MS SQL database from Java

Tags: c#, java, sql, sql-server, jakarta-ee

I am trying to call a stored procedure whose one parameter is `sqlstructure` type of MS SQL.I have passed `String[] array` but it threw this exception

```
WARNING: #{reportingCharts.getGraphValuesOnLocationBasis}: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{CALL dbo.up_Chart_SelectPersonCountByRankLocation(?,?,?,?,?)}]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; The conversion from UNKNOWN to UNKNOWN is unsupported.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The conversion from UNKNOWN to UNKNOWN is unsupported.
javax.faces.FacesException: #{reportingCharts.getGraphValuesOnLocationBasis}: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{CALL dbo.up_Chart_SelectPersonCountByRankLocation(?,?,?,?,?)}]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; The conversion from UNKNOWN to UNKNOWN is unsupported.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The conversion from UNKNOWN to UNKNOWN is unsupported.
```

So I think it is not accepting the `array` as a parameter for structure.
Unfortunately nowhere I can find an example about how to use it in java.
How can i pass my this array/list to this stored procedure? OR what would be the alternate for c#  `SqlDbType.Structured` in java?

Comment: Im not Java programmer, but maybe this will help: JDBC has separate ARRAY (java.sql.Array) and STRUCT (java.sql.Struct) data types. From the other side - im not sure that SQL Server can accept structures from JDBC.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375553/how-to-pass-userdefined-table-type-to-mssql-request-from-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [Microsoft JDBC Driver Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jdbcteam/) , the JDBC driver supported by TVP has not been released yet. There is a workaround :packing the values in a binary form ,cracking it on the server and passing it to a table valued function. For JDBC driver this argument has to be passed as binary.
See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378878.aspx) you will find all the MSsql datatypes for java.